# How do I extract the filename from a path in Awk if I have different length filenames with a path?

Tags: awk, filenames

I have an Awk script that counts the average of rows from every file from a given directory and its subdirectories and I have to print the filename and the average from a file like this

```
example.c : 5
```

So I have filenames like this `../labor1/munka/hazik_pagi4188/hazik/c_prog/lab1/fork2.c` and I want to get like this `fork2.c` (I have different length file names with path).

Comment: Why `awk`. `basename` is specifically designed for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "count the average of rows"?

Answer (score 0):

Try "recursive" `grep` and remove the path with `sed`, like

```
grep -rc "." | sed 's#^.*/##'
madsum.awk:11
zmz.awk:14
file_to_process.txt:2
```